# Hide a <div> set to display:block with jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I check a `div`'s visibility and, if the `div` is `display:block;`, hide it or, if the `div` is `display:none;`, leave it alone?

```
if(codition){
    $(".thanks").fadeIn('slow');
    $(".thanks").html(json[0]);
    $(".thanks").css('color','red');
}else{
    //HERE I want to check if the thanks div is display:block,hide it other wise ignore it    
    $(".errordiv").css('color','green');
    $(".errordiv").fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: Querying with `$(".thanks")` in three consecutive statements is one of the big anti-patterns of jQuery...

Comment: what he means is do `var thanks = $(".thanks"); thanks.fadeIn(); thanks.html(); thanks.css();`

Comment: Or `$("#.thanks").fadeIn('slow').html(json[0]).css('color', 'red')`.

Comment: because this will perform way better, because the "class selector" is not native JS and jquery has to traverse the whole DOM tree each time you write $('.thanks'). Writing it only a single time traverses the tree only a single time.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not even worth checking if it's already visible, just call hide. eg.

```
$('.thanks').hide();
```

Comment: it is hidden in css,if condition satisfied it will be unhide,second timw when the same script is called with jquery,if condition not satisfied then the thanks div must be hide,if it is block

Comment: Checking if its visible is absolutely not needed at all if your intent is to hide it. You simply need to hide it. Regardless of whether display:none was set from CSS or dynamically, the result of your check does not differ. If you need to check its visibility for any other purpose you can use `if($('div').is(':visible'))`

Answer (score 2):

Could you use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector?

```
if($('div').is(':visible')){
//execute
}
```

Alternatively, I suppose you might be able to check its [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) value:

```
if($('div').css('display')=='block'){
//execute
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css method

```
if ($(".errordiv").css('display') == 'block') {
   //display is equal to block, use .hide();
}
```

Also, I'd like to note that if you only have one element, you're better off referring to it by an ID rather than a class. It's a micro optimization, but it's cleaner and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
var elem1, elem2;

elem1 = $( '.thanks' )[0];
elem2 = $( 'errordiv' )[0];

if ( codition ) {
    $( elem1 ).html( json[0] ).addClass( 'class1' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
} else {
    if ( $( elem1 ).is( ':visible' ) ) { $( elem1 ).hide(); }
    $( elem2 ).addClass( 'class2' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
}
```

You have classes - `"class1"` and `"class2"` in my code, but you would of course have better names - to add the presentation to the elements.

---

***Let me explain...***

So, this:

```
var elem = $( '#test' )[0];
```

is equivalent to this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById( 'test' );
```

I use the `$( '#...' )[0]` notation as a shorthand for `.getElementsById()`.

Comment: Why do you unwrap the DOM element from the jQuery object only to then re-wrap it in the if statement?

Comment: @Sime Vidas thank you,exactly what i want,as i am knew please explan for what purpose you write $( '.thanks' )[0];

Comment: @a'r I like having direct references to the DOM elements. I prefer `elem` and `$( elem )` to `$elem` and `$elem[0]`...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas nice explaination,i get the point,which solved my problem.thanks

Comment: It is silly to wrap and unwrap like that - you are re-instantiating the jQuery object.. you would be better of creating an additional local variable.

Comment: @rlemon It's not silly. I like the `$( elem )` notation. Wrapping the same DOM reference repeatedly in a jQuery object is OK.

Comment: you are taking a hit for personal convenience, which may not be an issue for you, however it is not a recommended practise.

Comment: @rlemon I don't think I'm taking a hit. Initialization of a jQuery object takes a fractal of a microsecond. (A microsecond is one thousandth of a millisecond.)

Comment: you are taking a hit... 'a fractal of a microsecond. (A microsecond is one thousandth of a millisecond.)' hit to use your own words... i'm not saying it is horribly wrong. just silly and not your average practise. if it works for you by all means, but suggesting it to others will be misleading.

Comment: @rlemon I don't consider a fractal of a microsecond a hit. Therefore, I don't consider your argument against `$( elem )` valid.

Comment: ok - to anyone else reading this in the future - unless you have a good reason to do so, do not instantiate objects twice like this.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
if ($('div.errordiv:visible').length) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you could use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to do this.

```
<div class='mixedDisplay' style='display: none;'>Hello</div>
<div class='mixedDisplay'>World</div>
$('.mixedDisplay').toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/Y8RwV/

I understand it's not exactly what you are looking for, but it might be useful.